# Creating a hill out of a plane

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to grab a group of vertices and pull them upwards. And instead of the having just that area go up, can all the other vertices move in a beautiful manner (don't know how else to explain it)?

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is called [proportional editing](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/proportional_edit.html). It allows you to select a point or set of points, and when you move those points other nearby vertices will move along with them.

To use proportional editing, enter *Edit Mode* by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then look on the bottom of the window and enable *Proportional Editing* (you can also use the hotkey <kbd>O</kbd> while in edit mode to toggle proportional editing).

[image]

To the right of that menu there is the *Proportional Editing Falloff* menu, which lets you select how nearby vertices will be affected.

[image]

Once you have proportional editing turned on, select a vertex and move it, and the nearby vertices should move along with it. To broaden or narrow the effect, use the mouse scroll wheel.

[image]

<sup>Images are courtesy of the [Blender Manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/proportional_edit.html) and the [Blender Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit).</sup>

Comment: Page Up and Page Down keys also increase / decrease the proportional edit size.  My mouse scroll wheel can be finicky.

Comment: Sometimes it's also may help to sculpt that plane even if it has no Multires, when just making dirty mesh.